# php filter by user

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

ive got list of reports. for default, **the report list will be showing all reports without filtering. when drop down filter click, it will filter the result by name**. anyidea how to fix it?

```
function getReportSingleMonth($month, $year, $id_user=NULL) {
   $month = $db->real_escape_string($month);
   $year = $db->real_escape_string($year);
   $db->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE MONTH(date)='$month' AND YEAR(date)='$year' AND id_user='$id_user'");
}
```

the html part:

```
<form method="post" name="report_filter" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?report&month=<?= $_GET['month'];?>&year=<?= $_GET['year'];?>">
<div align="right"><select name="user_name" onchange="report_filter.submit();"><option value="--">Filter by:</option><option value="1">Andi</option>M<option value="2">Jenny</option><select></div>    
<? if(isset($_POST['user_name'])):
    $admin->getReportSingleMonth($_GET['month'], $_GET['year'], $_POST['user_name'])     
else :
    $admin->getReportSingleMonth($_GET['month'], $_GET['year']);
endif;
?>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you post the actual HTML output as well?

Comment: Is the closing `</select>` a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In older versions of MySQL you can't put quotes around integer values. Try switching this line:

```
$db->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE MONTH(date)='$month' AND YEAR(date)='$year'" AND id_user=$id_user");
```

Looking again, I noticed that you're not always going to pass a `user_id`. With that in mind the function should be changed:

```
function getReportSingleMonth($month, $year, $id_user=NULL) {
    $month = $db->real_escape_string($month);
    $year = $db->real_escape_string($year);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE MONTH(date)='$month' AND YEAR(date)='$year'";
    if ( is_int( $id_user ) ) {
        $query .= ' and id_user=' . $id_user;
    }
    $db->query( $query );
}
```

Now the `id_user` part of the query is only added if it was passed to the function.

I also recommend using [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

Comment: thanks alot. but seems still not working. ive got another line `GROUP BY time ORDER BY time ASC'. where should i put that line?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you need to change this:

```
$admin->getReportSingleMonth($_GET['month'], $_GET['year'], $_POST['user_name']);
```

It looks like your function for getting reports requires as user id (assuming an integer value) and you appear to be sending it a string using the $_POST['user_name'] value.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some (probable) issues:

1. Your `getReportSingleMonth()` seems to do filter `$month` and `$year` but not `$id_user` (i.e. [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection))
2. As others pointed out, you quote the `id_user` value in your SQL query.
3. You do not close the `<select>` tag.
4. You have a `<option value="--">` which will be treated like the intended user options (change to `value=""`).